# Facebook and Gplus login works intermitten

Tags: facebook, authentication, google-plus, whmcs

In a `WHMCS` installation I have  `Facebook` and `G+` automated `login/sign-up` buttons.

https://cardse.net/image/vN4

But these buttons do not work every time. When it fails `Facebook`, it also fails `G+`.

https://cardse.net/image/vNC

Credentials are ok, `APIs` are ok. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Please advice, what could be the issue. `WHMCS` support suggests a server error. But i don't buy it...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself

The intermitend function happened because of missing SSL handshake. After installing a SSL certificate on the portal, the buttons worked fine.